# How to find out which app icons disappear after updating?

Tags: updates

It happened a few times already that after updating my apps, I notice a gap on my homescreen where an app icon is missing (normally I have it completely filled so a single missing icon is easily noticed).

Is there a way to find out what happened to the app, and more importantly, which app it was? It's hard to keep track of all the stuff I have installed, but the apps I have on my homescreen are normally at least somewhat essential so I'd like to make sure I'm not missing anything important without knowing.

Comment: If you update the apps manually, consider taking a screenshot of your homescreen before updating.

Comment: @Ak. Sure, would make sense, I'd just prefer some sort of log or whatever where I can see what happened.

Comment: Upvoted.  I've seen this happen too.  I think it's a longstanding bug in either Android, the Google Play store, or the launcher.